# Subsetting dissimilarities and clustering the subset

Tags: r, clustering, similarities

I'm not sure whether to ask this here, or in an R specific forum. I'll try here, and perhaps someone can help. If mods think this is incorrectly posted, please close it and I'll try again on a different forum.

I have a matrix of mixed data, and I'm using Gower's coefficient to determine dissimilarity. I want to calculate dissimilarities, subset them and cluster the subset.

Some sample code, before I go further:

```
> x = matrix(seq(1:16), nrow=4, ncol=4)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
> y = daisy(x, metric = "gower")
> as.matrix(y)
          1         2         3         4
1 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000
2 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
3 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333
4 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.0000000
> as.matrix(y)[c(1, 3, 4), c(1, 3, 4)]
          1         3         4
1 0.0000000 0.6666667 1.0000000
3 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.3333333
4 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

Now, I want to take the last matrix, convert it to a dissimilarity and then feed it into a clustering algorithm. Can I do this, and is it correct to do so? And if yes, how do I do this?

Comment: You actually don't have to convert a similarity into dissimilarity. Most clustering methods can process both. But those that require only distance usually mean metric or just euclidean distance, which Gower dissimilarity is not.

Comment: Using a subset of a proximity matrix in clustering instead of the parent matrix - why not? That means you are using a subset of objects. However, with Gower you  should be wary: the values partially and potentially  depend on the number of objects. This is because range normalizing is used for interval variables, and range may depend on the objects available.